# MySQL sorting group-by results

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have the following tables structure:

*table_1*

```
id     title
------------
155    item1
156    item2
157    item3
```

*table_2*

```
id     model
------------
155    100
156    100
157    200
```

*table_3*

```
id     cid
------------
155    5
156    5
157    5
```

I want to group my results by **model** (from table_2) **and** make sure it returns the highest id (order by `id` descending).

I have tried the following, but the *order by* clause doesn't seem to work:

```
SELECT a.id, b.model FROM table_1 as a
INNER JOIN table_2 as b on b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN table_3 as c on c.id = a.id
WHERE c.cid = 5
GROUP BY b.model
ORDER BY a.id desc
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: put `MAX()` around `a.id`.  the selection of `a.id` in the result set is indeterminate without it

Comment: @MrUpsidown You really should put your output and error in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT max(a.id), b.model FROM table_1 as a
INNER JOIN table_2 as b on b.id = a.id
INNER JOIN table_3 as c on c.id = a.id
WHERE c.cid = 5
GROUP BY b.model
ORDER BY max(a.id) desc
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afb0b/2

The reason this works while your initial attempt did not, is that any field not present in the `GROUP BY` clause, or not used in an aggregate function (such as `MAX`), will have an indeterminate value (ie, the mysql engine makes no guarantees as to which value from the group you will get).

[MySQL GROUP BY Handling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-handling.html)

> The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.

In fact, MySQL is one of the few (only?) sql databases that will let you put a non aggregated, non grouped field in the select clause without erroring.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
select 
t1.id, 
t2.model 
from table_1 t1 join table_3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id 
join ( 
  select max(id) as id , model from table_2 group by model 
)t2 on t1.id=t2.id 
where t3.cid = 5;
```

Comment: In what would that be better than @pala_ answer? Seems to work fine too, but I just want to understand both ways. Thanks.

Comment: Using un-correlated subquery you can infact get more matching columns with respect to the table which is not possible in case of just doing `max` and `group by`